# Build ionic2 app for Windows10 fail when adding MobileFirst plugin

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, win-universal-app, ionic2

## The problem:

- I have an app in ionic2 that I could build for windows 10, until I added cordova-plugin-mbf (MBF version 8.0.0).
- When I added it, the build failed and asked me to add the argument --archs=x64
- With it, the build continue to fail but with this error "msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1"

## What i try:

- start a new project to validate that I can build without the plugin
- add the plugin to an empty project to validate that it's it who throw the error
- reinstall windows from scratch to be sure that my setup is correct
- build with node v5.12
- cry a lot

## My setup:

- Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.11
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.37
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
- OS: Node Version: v6.5.0
- Windows 10 version 1511; 10586.545
- Visual Studio 2015 comunity edition with :

  - microsoft web development tools
  - universal windows app development tools

    - tools (1.4.1) and windows 10 SDK (10.0.14393)
    - windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)
    - windows 10 SDK (10.0.10240)
  - windows 8.1 and windows phone 8.0/8.1 Tools

    - Tools and Windows SDK
  - emulator for Windows Phone 8.1

## The complete procedure:

Start a clean project :

```
ionic start testBuildWin10 -v2
cd testBuildWin10
```

setup config.xml to target windows10 instead of windows 8.1

```
<platform name="windows">
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
</platform>
```

At this step, the app works, but failed when adding mfp :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp
cordova prepare
ionic run windows
```

an error ask me to add the argument --archs=x64

> Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
>   C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
>   C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2
>
> add to body class: platform-windows
>
> Building project:
>   C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
>
> ```
>     Configuration : debug
>     Platform      : anycpu
> ```
>
> C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(83,9):
>   error : The following component requires .NET Native compilation which
>   is not available when targeting 'Windows10' and 'AnyCPU'. Consider
>   changing the targeted processor architecture to one of the following:
>   'x86, x64, ARM' (if you are using command line this could be done by
>   adding '--archs' parameter, for example: 'cordova build windows
>   --archs=x64'). C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2\platforms\windows\plugins\cordova-plugin-globalization\GlobalizationProxy.winmd
>
> Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command
>   failed with exit code 1

then when i run ionic run --archs=x64

> C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj(83,9):
>   error : The following component requires .NET Native compilation which
>   is not available when targeting 'Windows10' and 'AnyCPU'. Please
>   consider changing the targeted processor architecture to one of the
>   following: 'x86, x64, ARM' (if you are using command line this could
>   be done by adding '--archs' parameter, for example: 'cordova build
>   windows --archs=x64').
>   C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\testBuildWin10-2\platforms\windows\plugins\cordova-plugin-globalization\GlobalizationProxy.winmd
>
> Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command
>   failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobilefirst Windows SDK packages with architecture specific DLL's. Hence `ionic run windows` command will fail as it runs for `AnyCPU`.

In order to run platform specific commands you need to add `--` separator before `--archs=x64`.

Try with command `ionic run windows -- --archs=x64`, I hope it should resolve the issue.

Comment: outch :'( thank you for your answer. Have you a public roadmap somewhere ?

Comment: @EricD Can you test same application with following command `ionic run windows -- --archs=x64`